# Moderators Pro Tempore, fusion-style

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Xander]
[image: Jamie Eltringham]
[image: Monica Cellio]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

[Andrew Cheong](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/73) has stepped down as moderator, and we'd also like to thank him for his service to the site.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for stepping up to the plate or should I say bar as Moderators Pro Tempore. Congratulations and a warm welcome from everyone here! Looking forward to hearing from you in the future. I would like to extend a special thanks also to Andrew Cheong for all his hard work in the past.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for all you've done for this site!  Enjoy your retirement -- cheers!